# Descending order with string in constant position

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need to take input from the user and if the user enters string the program should keep integer in descending order and the position of the string should be in constant position. I am not being able to keep only integer in descending order.

```
public class sort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num;
        int i, j, temp;

        String nu;
        int y;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of character to be sort:");
        String num = input.nextLine();

        int length = num.length();
        String result = "";
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            Character character = num.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(character)) {
                result += character;
            }
        }

        int array[] = new int[num];
        System.out.println("Enter " + num + " character ");
        for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
            array[i] = input.nextInt();

        for (i = 0; i < (num - 1); i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < num - i - 1; j++) {
                if (array[j] < array[j + 1]) {
                    temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Sorted list of integers:");

        for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
            System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: For start you have defined the same variable twice `int num;` and then `String num = input.nextLine();` Add on your question the errors you are seeing.

Comment: Eh, as a side note, don't concatenate strings in a loop. Use a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some modifications to your code that might help. For one, Integer.ParseInt works better than nextInt() because nextInt() leaves a carriage return on nextLine(). Also I feel a while loop would work better for your bubble sort algorithm.

```
import java.util.*;
public class sort {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num;
    int i, temp;

    String nu;
    int y;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of character to be sort:");
    num = Integer.ParseInt(input.nextLine());

    int[] arr = new int[num];
    System.out.println("Enter " + num + " character ");
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
        arr[i] = Integer.ParseInt(input.nextLine());

    int swaps;
    while (swaps == 0) {
        swaps = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[i + 1]) {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = temp;
                swaps++;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Sorted list of integers:");

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
        System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I changed a few things. First of all, you declared num twice, and had a String = input.nextInt() which doesn't match. The try...catch checks if it's an int input, otherwise it converts it from a char to an int. Your algorithm to put them in descending order worked fine, but populating the array wasn't working.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class sort {


public static void main(String []args) {

int i, j, temp;


int y;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the number of character to be sort:");
String  num = input.nextLine();   


int length = Integer.parseInt(num);
String result = "";


int array[] = new int[length]; 
System.out.println("Enter " + num + " character ");
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  try{
    array[i]=input.nextInt();
  }catch(InputMismatchException e){
      Character c = input.next().charAt(0);
      array[i]=(int)(c.charValue());
  }
}

for (i = 0; i < ( length- 1 ); i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < length - i - 1; j++) {
    if (array[j] < array[j+1]) 
    {
      temp = array[j];
      array[j] = array[j+1];
      array[j+1] = temp;
    }
  }
}

System.out.println("Sorted list of integers:");

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: that was great but the thing is if the Input is 5 4 7 y 1 g 9  Output needs to be 9 7 5 y 4 g 1 so the output must be alphabet.. :)

Comment: Oh I get it, I'll figure it and edit my answer out later today.